# How to format date with Bootstrap-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-datepicker

I know how famous is this topic ... but my question is a little bit more complex.
I read documentation [here](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format)
I want to display date in french format (dd/mm/yyyy) and save value in US format (yyyy-mm-dd).
I also need to specified startDate which is first day of month.

I tried this configuration :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: {
      language: 'fr',
      toDisplay: function(date, format, language) {
        return date.getUTCDate() + "/" + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getUTCFullYear();
      },
      toValue: function(date, format, language) {
        return new Date(date);
      }
    },
    //startDate: function(date) {
    //    return date.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + date.getUTCMonth() + "-01";
    //},
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

But :

- Display Value : not really french format ... 7/9/2016 instead of
  07/09/2016
- StartDate : doesn't work

Anyone could help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using moment.js, it has a ton of time formatting logic, it's lightweight, easy to use, and has locale support.
http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I didn't know this library. It seems to be nice, but in my case I'm pretty sure I just need to use correctly bootstrap-datepicker ... but I don't know how to do ...

Comment: HOwever I will have a look on 'momentjs' ;-)

Comment: MomentJs is really cool :) I found how to get first day of month from given date :  var firstDayOfMonth = moment(dp.val()).startOf('month');

Answer (score 0):

Get value split it on "/" en rejoin them afterwards.

```
dateparts = datevalue.split("/");
d = dateparts[0];
m = dateparts[1];
y = dateparts[2];
newdate = y + "/" + m + "/" + d;
```

Then you can edit each part afterwards as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [i18n docs](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/i18n.html), if you want to localize you picker. Basically you have to import an additional js file with locale specific settings and then specify the [`language`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#language) option. This way you automatically customize displayed format.

Use the `format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'` if you just want to change the [format](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format). (E.g. No french names for months and days)

You don't need `toDisplay` and `toValue` to convert your date into the desired `YYYY-MM-DD` format, you can use an helper function as shown in the example below.

---

Note that [`startDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate) docs says that:

> String must be parsable with `format`.

The one in your example probably isn't parsable due to `-`.

Finally, I suggest to use momentjs to simplyfy both [first day of month calculation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) and [format conversion](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). Here there is a working example using moment and datepicker's i18n:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    language: 'fr',
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    startDate: moment().startOf('month').toDate()
  });
  
  $('#btnGetDate').click(function(){
    var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    var dateUsFormat = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log(dateUsFormat); // date formatted in YYYY-MM-DD
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
<button id="btnGetDate" class="btn btn-primary">Get Date</button>
```